Is Sequelize Truncating the JSON Response with Nested Relations?
If you look at the productPGs and variantPGs relationships you notice the keys are cutoff or truncated, why is that happening? This only happens when I use include: { all: true, nested: true } in the query builder and when there are 4 or more relations. I'm a noob to sequelize so maybe i'm missing some here. Using PostgreSQL. The field/key names should be the following:
"productPGs": 
    [ { 
        "id": 74, 
        "discountPercent": "50.56", 
        "productId": 161, 
        "pricingGroupId": 10, 
        "createdAt": "2024-10-27T00:21:59.182Z", 
        "updatedAt": "2024-10-27T00:21:59.182Z" 
    } ]

{
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 10,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 132,
            "discountAmount": "7.5",
            "subTotal": "457.5",
            ...
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "city": "LA",
                    "name": "Business Name",
                    "countryCode": "US"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2024-10-28T04:31:40.067Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-10-28T19:50:56.522Z",
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "id": 231,
                    ...
                    "orderId": 132,
                    "productVariant": {
                        "id": 370,
                        "title": "B201 ABC 123",
                        ...
                        "product": {
                            "id": 161,
                            "title": "B20044",
                            ...
                            "productPGs": [
                                {
                                    "id": 74,
                                    "discount": "50.56",
                                    "productI": 161,
                                    "pricingG": 10,
                                    "createdA": "2024-10-27T00:21:59.182Z",
                                    "updatedA": "2024-10-27T00:21:59.182Z"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "variantPGs": [
                            {
                                "id": 39,
                                "variantId": 370,
                                "pricingGroupId": 3,
                                "discountPercenta": "75.90"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "hasMore": false
}


Please add your DMBS type tag in the future posts (postgresql, mysql and so on)

Guessing it's PostgreSQL it's a column name limitation (up to 64 characters) that leads to such effect.
You just need to turn on the minifyAliases option in Sequelize constructor options to avoid having field names truncated, see constructor options

options.minifyAliases  boolean
optional default: false
A flag that defines if aliases should be minified (mostly useful to avoid Postgres alias character limit of 64)


minifyAliases default is false. I haven't changed this so i'm not sure if that is the cause. I will add it and set it false explicitly to see if it has any affect.

On contrary, you need to set it to true
